# Memory leak message when i'm using history.push inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs

When I'm passing history.push in a UseEffect function.

```
function Home(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await listingService.allListingDetails(data.listingId);

      let tasksReceived = response.data.tasks;
      let tasks = [...tasksReceived];
      setTasks(tasks);
      setListing(response.data);

      if (tasks.length < 1) {
        history.push({
          pathname: "/firstpage",
          state: {
            listing: response.data,
          },
        });

        return;
      }
    };
  }, [changeState]);
}
```

index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
at Home (http://localhost:3001/static/js/main.chunk.js:11116:79)

If I'm commenting the below line, the memory leak error doesn't come anymore.

```
      if (tasks.length < 1) {
        history.push({
          pathname: "/firstpage",
          state: {
            listing: response.data,
          },
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that react is trying to apply the state updates of `setTasks` and `setListing` after the redirection happens and the component is already unmounted, remember that state updates are not immediate but batched. Try reordering the logic by setting the state only if you have tasks since updating the state when you're redirecting is meaningless.

```
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await listingService.allListingDetails(data.listingId);
      let tasksReceived = response.data.tasks;
      let tasks = [...tasksReceived];
      if (tasks.length < 1) {
        history.push({
          pathname: "/firstpage",
          state: {
            listing: response.data,
          },
        });
      } else {
        setTasks(tasks);
        setListing(response.data);
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because react is performing a state update at the same moment that you're trying to navigate (history.push). Try separating the code (the fetching in one side, the state update in another...) and return the history.push (cleanup function).

```
function Home(props) {

  useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await listingService.allListingDetails(data.listingId);
          let tasksReceived = response.data
          return tasksReceived;
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
          return null;
        }
      }

      const data = fetchData().then((data) => data);
      setTasks(data?.tasks || []);
      setListing(data || {});
      

      if (data?.tasks.length < 1) {
        return () => history.push({
          pathname: "/firstpage",
          state: {
            listing: response.data,
          },
        });
      }
  }, [changeState]);
}
```

Comment: you can't pass an async function to `useEffect`

Answer (score 0):

This is common error when updating a state after component is unmonted.

It may be due to concurrency or due to calling the use effect unnecessary depending on the **[changeState]** arg

For traceability, you can debug to put the following console.logs()

```js
const renderCount = 0;
const useEffectCallCount = 0;

function Home(props) {
  console.log(`Redering ${renderCount++}`);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      useEffectCallCount++;
      const callId = useEffectCallCount;
      console.log(`useEfect initiated. CallID: ${callId}`);
      const response = await listingService.allListingDetails(data.listingId);

      let tasksReceived = response.data.tasks;
      let tasks = [...tasksReceived];
      console.log(`updating component state. CallID:  ${callId}`);
      setTasks(tasks);
      setListing(response.data);

      if (tasks.length < 1) {
        console.log(`Redirecting to first page. CallID:  ${callId}`);
        history.push({
          pathname: "/firstpage",
          state: {
            listing: response.data,
          },
        });
      }
    };

  ///probably missing from the example is calling the fetchDataItself. Fire and forget
  fetchData();

 /// we return clean-up function, but in this case, we want just to perform console.log
  return () => { console.log("Component is dismounted"); }
  }, [changeState]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since setting a state is async it will end up at the end of the callback queue and wait for other sync tasks to be finished.

If the redirect happens it tries to update the state of a component that is no longer mounted.

Try using code from below

```js
function Home(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await listingService.allListingDetails(data.listingId);

      let tasksReceived = response.data.tasks;
      let tasks = [...tasksReceived];

      if (tasks.length < 1) {
        history.push({
          pathname: "/firstpage",
          state: {
            listing: response.data,
          },
        });
        
        // This return finished the function
        return;
      }
      
      // Only set these state if the redirect didn't happen
      setTasks(tasks);
      setListing(response.data);
    };
  }, [changeState]);
}
```